# Can Stripe have status as active and trialing at the same time?

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, php-7

Is it possible to have status as active and trialing both?
Following code works for active subscription but I also want to retrieve data having status as "trialing".

```
$all_subs = \Stripe\Subscription::all(
                     array(
                             "plan" => $group_plan_id,
                            "status" => "active",
                            'limit' => 100
                         )

                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation specifically says "one of...", so you can only choose one status per call. You will need to either make two calls with each status type, or use the status `"all"` to get ALL of the types (which will also return `cancelled`, `past_due`, and `unpaid`) and then filter out the ones you don't want.

```
$all_subs = \Stripe\Subscription::all(
             array(
                 "plan" => $group_plan_id,
                 "status" => "all",
                 "limit" => 100
             )
         );
$statuses = array('active','trialing');
foreach ($all_subs->data as $sub) {
    if (!in_array($sub->status,$statuses)) {
        continue;
    }

    // do some code here
}
```

Source: [Stripe API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#list_subscriptions)

Comment: Thanks for the help @spartacus. 
Can you explain what $sub->status do? 
As far I know $all_subs is JSON and  $statuses is array.Is there any other solution?

Comment: I actually made a mistake in my answer. Edited. `$all_subs`, because you're using the PHP Stripe library, is not JSON but a PHP object. This object contains some key/value pairs, then an array of subscription objects. You need to loop through that array, which is at `$all_subs->data`, then get the status of each subscription by using `$sub->status`

Comment: Thank you so much @spartacus. Gotcha